# Selecting an XML subset with Nokogiri

Tags: xml-parsing, nokogiri

For my first discovery of Nokogiri and XML parsing, I need to extract a list of Code items (with their children) provided a webservice. The document looks like this:

```
<message:Structure xmlns:common="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/common" xmlns:structure="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/structure" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:message="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message SDMXMessage.xsd">
  <message:Header>
    <message:ID>70c32d97-bbd5-44c7-8bff-50a63abe07eb</message:ID>
    <message:Test>false</message:Test>
    <message:Prepared>2021-08-26T11:37:37</message:Prepared>
    <message:Sender id="CH1">
      <message:Name>CH1</message:Name>  
    </message:Sender>
  </message:Header>
  <message:CodeLists>
    <structure:CodeList id="CL_LEISTUNGSART" version="1.0" agencyID="CH1" isFinal="true">
      <structure:Name xml:lang="de">Leistungsart</structure:Name>
      <structure:Name xml:lang="fr">Type prestation</structure:Name>
      <structure:Name xml:lang="it">Tipo di prestazione</structure:Name>
      <structure:Code value="01">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="02">
        <structure:Description xml:lang="de">Reguläre Unterstützung mit Zielvereinbarung</structure:Description>
        <structure:Description xml:lang="fr">Aide financière régulière avec contrat d'insertion</structure:Description>
        <structure:Description xml:lang="it">Assistenza regolare con contratto d’inserimento</structure:Description>
        <structure:Annotations>
        </structure:Annotations>
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="03">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="04">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="05">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="10">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="21">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="22">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="23">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="25">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="26">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="32">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="33">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="34">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="35">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="36">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="37">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="40">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Code value="50">
      </structure:Code>
      <structure:Annotations>
      </structure:Annotations>
    </structure:CodeList>
    <structure:CodeList id="CL_LEISTUNGSART" version="2.0" agencyID="CH1">
    </structure:CodeList>
  </message:CodeLists>
</message:Structure>
```

The request is: select the one CodeList from the structure where **version is the highest value and  isFinal is true**, and then read the Code elements (with their children).

I can select the CodeList elements from the structure namespace:

```
document.css("structure|CodeList")
```

but then I get lost when trying to evaluate attributes **version** and **isFinal**.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll probably be better off using xpath instead of css selectors, but your xml is not well formed so it's hard to tell. Try to edit the question with well formed xml.

Comment: Your xml has two `<structure:CodeList>` elements; one has the highest attribute value of the `version` attribute (i.e., "2.0") but no `isFinal` attribute; the other does have that attribute with the value "true", but a lower `version` attribute value. So nothing meets your condition. Do you mean to search for the `<structure:CodeList>` with the highetst `version` attribute value from those that have the `isFinal` attribute?

Comment: Also, your xml is still not well formed. Run it first by [something like this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp).

Comment: Thank you for helping on my question! The copy paste has truncated the message, it is now corrected and passes validation. Yes I am searching for the CodeList with the higest version from those having isFinal = true.  I'll switch to xPath if it is easier to solve :-)

Answer (score 1):

For reasons you'll see below, this is not really an answer, but it's too long for a comment and may help to some extent.

In terms of pure xpath expressions, to get (for example), the French language translation of the `structure:Name` child node of the `structure:CodeList` node (which meets your two requirements), the following expression

```
//structure:CodeList[@version=max(//*[@isFinal="true"]/number(@version))]/structure:Name[@xml:lang="fr"]/text()
```

would output

```
Type prestation
```

and similarly for other languages or, for example `structure:Description`. Since the xml uses namespaces, for nokogiri  you'll have to use something like

```
doc.xpath('//structure:CodeList[@version=max(//*[@isFinal="true"]/number(@version))]/structure:Name[@xml:lang="fr"]/text()',
                'structure' => "http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/structure")
```

The problem is the use of the `max()` function in the expression. I can't test it myself right now, but `max()` is an xpath 2.0 function and my understanding is that only xpath 1.0 is supported.

One why to possibly address the issue of support for later xpath versions is to [take a look here](https://github.com/fidothe/saxon-rb).